# Javascript: modify String's [[PrimitiveValue]] using "this"

Tags: javascript

I ran into a situation that need someone with intimate knowledge about JavaScript primitive.

Problem: I wanted to extend String and add a function called "extract" which function just like "substr" but in the process of returning the sub-string, it also removes the sub-string from the original string.

Take for example, the following doesn't work.

```
if (!String.prototype.extract) {
  String.prototype.extract = function (delimiter) {
    var copyStr = "";
    var i = this.indexOf(delimiter);
    if (i >= 0) {
      copyStr = this.substr(0, i);
      console.log(this); <<-- "String" 

      //This line doesn't work, don't know what [[PrimitiveValue]] is.
      this.[[PrimitiveValue]] = this.replace(copyStr + delimiter,"");      

      // Nor this line works.  Can't modify 'this'
      this = this.replace(copyStr + delimiter, ""); 
    }
    return copyStr;
  }
}
```

Then I could call like this:

```
var str = "abcdef";
var str2 = str.extract('c');  
console.log(str); <<-- this should be 'def'
console.log(str2); <<-- this should be 'abc'
```

I could write a stand alone function like below that returns both the sub-string and the modified original string, but that's beside the point.

```
function extractSubString(originalStr, delimiter) {
    var copyStr = "";
    var i = originalStr.indexOf(delimiter);
        if (i >= 0) {
            copyStr = originalStr.substr(0, i);
            originalStr = original.replace(copyStr + delimiter, "");
        }  
    return copyStr;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: There's not really a way, as Felix Kling has already covered in his answer. Best options is probably going to be packaging both values into a return object. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ju20400m/

Answer (score 2):

> but in the process of returning the sub-string, it also removes the sub-string from the original string.

Strings are **immutable**, meaning their values cannot be modified in any way.

Comment: Right.  However, all primitive wrappers have the [[PrimitiveValue]] and one can get to the raw through the "valueOf()" function.  If we can get the raw value, I just thought there might be a way to write back to it.

Comment: Nope, there isn't :) The specification doesn't specify any methods to change the internal slot after the object was initialized.

Comment: @FelixKling It would be cool if you could give a link about the specification :)